# prior storage driver "aufs" failed: driver not supported Error starting daemon: error initializing graphdriver: driver not supported

Tags: ubuntu, docker, ubuntu-14.04

When a try to run docker locally in ubuntu 14.04 when i run this line in the console:

```
sudo docker -d
```

The console show me this error:

```
Warning: '-d' is deprecated, it will be removed soon. See usage.
WARN[0000] please use 'docker daemon' instead.          
ERRO[0000] [graphdriver] prior storage driver "aufs" failed: driver not supported 
FATA[0000] Error starting daemon: error initializing graphdriver: driver not supported
```

Answer (score 44):

Try removing all downloaded images:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/docker/aufs -rf
```

That helped me to recover docker after a kernel update.

Related issues on the github:

- https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/14026
- https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/15651

Comment: Switch your options on rm.

`sudo rm /var/lib/docker/aufs -rf`

Option placement doesn't matter and it makes your command safe until the last two characters.  Confirm that you are ok with deleting a directory with -r after typing everything out.

Comment: Worked for me as well

Comment: This deleted all my containers ... damn.

Comment: @kkazakov What else did you expect from a command that is exclusively used for deleting things and an answer that states explicitly that this will delete all your images?

Answer (score 24):

I had the same problem after a kernel update that removed the AUFS driver. What fixed it was:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-extra-`uname -r` && sudo modprobe aufs
```

If future updates break the driver again, bundle the command with your update:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && apt-get -y install linux-image-extra-$(uname -r) aufs-tools
```

For differences between apt-get upgrade and dist-upgrade, see [Why use apt-get upgrade instead of apt-get dist-upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/194651/why-use-apt-get-upgrade-instead-of-apt-get-dist-upgrade/226213#226213).

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in [ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/690825/286561), unfortunately you have to completely purge your previous docker installation by running:

```
sudo apt-get purge docker-engine
```

resp.

```
sudo apt-get purge docker.io
```

then you have to remove `/var/lib/docker` (Or move it to a different name, if you first want to try if everything works.)

```
sudo rm /var/lib/docker
```

resp.

```
sudo mv /var/lib/docker /var/lib/docker.old
```

Afterwards you can install the `docker-engine` package again.

The same procedure applies for debian.

Answer (score 2):

There are some problems with the kernel in ubuntu so the best way to run docker is with this line:

```
sudo docker -d --storage-driver=overlay
```

Comment: Ok, this works, but how would I configure this, that docker can be started by systemd?

Comment: You have to edit systemd config files, which vary from setup to setup.  This is how I ended up setting up my system on Ubuntu 16.04 https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/systemd/#custom-docker-daemon-options, but I changed the ExecStart: ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon $DOCKER_OPTS -H fd:// --storage-driver=overlay

Comment: btw the `-d` is deprecated, the command now would be `sudo docker daemon --storage-driver=overlay`