# Cannot connect to the Docker daemon After I update the linux kernel

Tags: linux, docker, linux-kernel

The docker daemon worked fine before, but after I update the linux kernel version from `4.10` to `4.12`, I found that the Docker daemon can't work:

When I run `docker ps` comes the error:

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

and I run `systemctl status docker.service` to see the details, it outputs the error:

```
systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
```

and the detail error from `dockerd':`

`ERRO[0001] [graphdriver] prior storage driver aufs failed: driver not supported 
Error starting daemon: error initializing graphdriver: driver not supported`

OS: `linux Ubuntu 16.04 LTS`   kernel: `v4.12`,  docker version :`Docker version 17.07.0-ce, build 8784753`

Comment: Run `docker daemon -D` in a terminal and see if you get an errors

Comment: you need to provide more information like OS and its version, docker version, logs ..

Comment: My experience is to reinstall virtualbox-dkms package after linux kerel update.

Comment: Include the log detail from `journalctl -u docker.service`

Comment: Now I have edited the question with the deatil error information. Thanks.

Comment: You may wanna switch to overlayfs. aufs is not supported by the kernel any more. I know that this is a very annoying situation. But switching to overlayfs is not that complicated. Check the internet for that :)

Comment: May be there is the answer for your question: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33357824/prior-storage-driver-aufs-failed-driver-not-supported-error-starting-daemon
or
https://askubuntu.com/questions/870889/cant-start-docker-on-ubuntu-16-04-with-driver-not-supported-error/870890

Comment: thanks. This worked