# docker.io error when upgrading packages on linux mint

Tags: linux, docker, linux-mint, dpkg

So I have docker installed on Linux Mint 18.3 (dual-boot with Windows 7) and I can run and work with the containers without an issue. However, ever since I installed it, I keep getting errors while I try to upgrade my packages.

> Calculating upgrade... Done
>   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
>   1 not fully installed or removed.
>   After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
>   Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
>   Setting up docker.io (1.13.1-0ubuntu1~16.04.2) ...
>   addgroup: The group `docker' already exists and is not a system group. Exiting.
>   dpkg: error processing package docker.io (--configure):
>    subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
>   Errors were encountered while processing:
>    docker.io
>   E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

I tried to install docker.io again and see what happens:

> $ sudo apt-get install docker.io
>   Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   docker.io is already the newest version (1.13.1-0ubuntu1~16.04.2).
>   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
>   1 not fully installed or removed.
>   After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
>   Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
>   Setting up docker.io (1.13.1-0ubuntu1~16.04.2) ...
>   addgroup: The group `docker' already exists and is not a system group. Exiting.
>   dpkg: error processing package docker.io (--configure):
>    subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
>   Errors were encountered while processing:
>    docker.io
>   E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Running `$ groups` returns this:

> $ groups
>   kosara adm dialout cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare docker

I did some digging and ran `$ sudo dpkg --configure -a`:

> $ sudo dpkg --configure -a
>   Setting up docker.io (1.13.1-0ubuntu1~16.04.2) ...
>   addgroup: The group `docker' already exists and is not a system group. Exiting.
>   dpkg: error processing package docker.io (--configure):
>    subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
>   Errors were encountered while processing:
>    docker.io

But it seems that a package that isn't fully installed is to blame, so I tried to fix it:

> $ sudo apt-get -f install
>   Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
>   1 not fully installed or removed.
>   After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
>   Setting up docker.io (1.13.1-0ubuntu1~16.04.2) ...
>   addgroup: The group `docker' already exists and is not a system group. Exiting.
>   dpkg: error processing package docker.io (--configure):
>    subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
>   Errors were encountered while processing:
>    docker.io
>   E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

I removed docker and did a clean install, to no avail. I'm not really sure what to try next and I couldn't find a solution that works for me so far. Any help would be welcome!

Comment: try removing all downloaded images: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35654852/3531155

Comment: @user3531155 I ended up switching to ubuntu since mint doesn't support docker-ce (which is what I originally wanted to use) but I'd still like to know why docker.io kept giving me trouble;
I've also tried what you suggested with no success